# Как десериализовать неизвестный класс GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Например, у нас чередуются данные

```
{
  "orderID": 12345,
  "shopperName": "Ваня Иванов",
  "shopperEmail": "ivanov@example.com",
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "Image",
      "Url": "https://someurl.com",
    },
    {
      "type": "Text",
      "text": "some text",
      "isItalic": true,
      "isBold": true
    }
  ],
  "orderCompleted": true
}
```

Можно ли представить contents как массив HashMap'ов? Допустим, у меня есть 2 класса: Image и Text, как мне определить к какому классу принадлежит элемент в массиве contents?

```
    public class RawCollectionsExample {
  static class Event {
    private String name;
    private String source;
    private Event(String name, String source) {
      this.name = name;
      this.source = source;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("(name=%s, source=%s)", name, source);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Collection collection = new ArrayList();
    collection.add("hello");
    collection.add(5);
    collection.add(new Event("GREETINGS", "guest"));
    String json = gson.toJson(collection);
    System.out.println("Using Gson.toJson() on a raw collection: " + json);
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
    String message = gson.fromJson(array.get(0), String.class);
    int number = gson.fromJson(array.get(1), int.class);
    Event event = gson.fromJson(array.get(2), Event.class);
    System.out.printf("Using Gson.fromJson() to get: %s, %d, %s", message, number, event);
  }
}
```

В данном примере мы точно знаем экземпляром какого класса является элемент в массиве

Comment: в заголовке GSON или JSON?

Comment: Конкретно GSON, т.к. сейчас именно эта библиотека используется в проекте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант - вы можете создать класс, включающий как свойства `Image`, так и свойства `Text` и, в последствии, различать их по свойству `type`

Второй вариант - вы можете определить [собственный десериализатор](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/).

[Ссылка на джавадоки](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать с помощью класса [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java), сразу получив нужные pojo. Класс отсутствует в gson'е, надо скопировать локально. Будет что-то типа:

```
class Order {
    @SerializedName("contents") List<Content> contents;
}

class Content {
}

class ImageContent extends Content {
    @SerializedName("Url") private String url;
}

class TextContent extends Content {
    @SerializedName("text") String text;
    @SerializedName("isItalic") boolean italic;
    @SerializedName("isBold") boolean bold;
}

Order getOrder(String jsonString){
    RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Content> contentAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Content.class, "type")
           .registerSubtype(ImageContent.class, "Image")
           .registerSubtype(TextContent.class, "Text");

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(contentAdapterFactory).create();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, Order.class);
}
```

NB В классах нет поля type, оно присутствует только в json'е, как при сериализации, так нужно для десериализации.

ЗЫ Есть [баг](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/712), там же решение. Без него не работает как надо.